# Knockout Search / Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm very new to Knockout JS and I'm having a hell of a time trying to get this project completed.

I've created a map website which displays a series of pins on the page for popular locations around town. The idea is that the search bar to the left of the page will filter out pins on the map with names that do not match the search query. There is also a "master" list on the left of the page that the search bar will filter from too.

I used an example I found on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mythical/XJEzc/ but I'm having troubles applying that same logic to my code.

Here it is:

HTML:

```
        <li>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="filter" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
        </li>
        <ul data-bind="template: {name:'pin', foreach: pins}"></ul> 
    </ul>

<script type="text/html" id="pin">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
    </li>
</script>
```

JS:

```
self.pins = ko.observableArray([
  new self.mapPin("Anchorage Alaska", 61.190491, -149.868937, "test1"),
  new self.mapPin("Anchorage Alaska", 61.190491, -149.868937, "test2")
]);

self.query = ko.observable('');

self.filterPins = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var search = self.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(name, function (pin) {
        return pin.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
});
```

With the logic I've setup if the name is removed from the pin constructor it will remove it from the map.

Here is my somewhat working example: http://jamesiv.es/projects/map/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'pin', foreach: pins}"></ul>
```

change to

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'pin', foreach: filterPins}"></ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
self.filterPins = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var search = self.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.name, function (pin) {
        return pin.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
});
```

change to

```
self.filterPins = ko.computed(function () {
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pins(), function (pin) {
        return pin.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: That did not seem to do the trick, the names are no longer displaying and the filtering does not work. I updated the page here:  http://jamesiv.es/projects/map/  -- Thanks for looking at it, I appreciate the help!

Comment: ah you have declare your array as observable array, and each object property as observable..
we should call it as function instead of variable, I updated  the code, see if its work on your end

Comment: That did the trick. Now I just need to figure out how to remove the actual pins from the map if it does not match the query. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, since Knockout 2.0 dependent observables are now called computed observables.

Comment: Just used this to implement search. So slick. I returned the original object if search was null:  self.filteremployeeUsers = ko.computed(function () {
        var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
        if (search) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.employeeUsers(), function (employee) {
                return (employee.firstName().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) || employee.lastName().toLowerCase().indexOf(search))>= 0;
            });

        }
        else {
            return self.employeeUsers();
        }
      
    });

Answer (score 1):

Just want to update the code if using Knockout version newer than 3.2

Change from `value` and `valueUpdate` to `textInput`, as reccomended [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html)

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="filter" data-bind="textInput: query" autocomplete="off" />
```

JS:

```
this.query = ko.observable('');

this.filteredPins = ko.computed(function () {
    if (this.query()) {
        var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.pins(), function (pin) {
            return pin.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
        });
    } else {
        return pins
    }}, this);
```